# Designing a Guava LoadingCache with variable entry expiry

Tags: java, multithreading, guava

I am using Guava's LoadingCache into my project to handle thread-{safe,friendly} cache loading and it works wonderfully well. However, there is a limitation.

The current code defining the cache looks like this:

```
cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().maximumSize(100L).build(new CacheLoader<K, V>()
{
    // load() method implemented here
}
```

I don't specify an expiry time.

The problem is that according to the values of the key, some associated values may expire and others may not. And `CacheLoader` does not account for this, if you specify an expiry time, it is for each and every entry.

How would you tackle this problem?

Comment: Why don't you use 2 caches: one with expiration, another for eternal entities?

Comment: Because the entry expiration is completely random (ie, consider HTTP with different `Cache-Control` headers).

Comment: Then I suggest you to include expiration time directly to your entry class and manually evict it from cache if it is expired immediately after you fetched it from cache.

Comment: Care to elaborate? How do you do that using Guava API?

Comment: get / check item expiration / invalidate

Comment: As an alternative, I can suggest you to check EhCache library that supports per element expire policy

Comment: [Guava issue 1203](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=1203&can=1&q=cache&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Type%20Status%20Package%20Summary)

Comment: @hoaz: I'll definitely look into ehcache, it looks promising...

Comment: @LouisWasserman: this issue adds expiry time at entry insertion, ideally I want this information to be in the entry itself.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Another alternative is my [ExpiringMap](https://github.com/jhalterman/expiringmap) (I'm the author), which supports variable entry expiration:

```
Map<String, String> map = ExpiringMap.builder().variableExpiration().build();
map.put("foo", "bar", ExpirationPolicy.ACCESSED, 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
map.put("baz", "pez", ExpirationPolicy.CREATED, 10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

Comment: Thanks for the link! Since your mention of it I have asked the author about implementing loading for entries which he has done and tested... Truly a great find!

Comment: "Entries can have individually variable expiration times and policies"  Great find.  Thanks.

Comment: This looks great! Planning to use it for auth ID token caching.

Answer (score 13):

I suggest you to include expiration time directly to your entry class and manually evict it from cache if it is expired immediately after you fetched it from cache:

```
MyItem item = cache.getIfPresent(key);
if (item != null && item.isExpired()) {
    cache.invalidate(key);
    item = cache.get(key);
    // or use cache.put if you load it externally
}
```

As an alternative, I can suggest you to check EhCache library that supports per element expire policy.

Comment: This helps to avoid using expired entries but they still cost memory - they stay in the cache only to be invalidated and reloaded.

Comment: thats is why i suggested to use more mature cache implementation :)

Comment: This is very, very close to what I want to do, and I will indeed look into ehcache. The only problems I have with it is the sheer dependency size (more than the whole of Guava!) and that I'd need to make keys and values implement `Serializable`. Ugh. I guess it cannot be helped...

Comment: Ha ha!  "use more mature cache implementation".  Yeah, Guava not having a per-item expiration is a real downer.   Thanks for EhCache suggestion!

Answer (score 7):

`LoadingCache` offers some commonly used expiration policies, but when these fall short for what you need, you need to roll your own.

Just add a [DelayQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/DelayQueue.html). Whenever you add something to the cache, add a `Delayed` to that queue, with the appropriate expiration time. The `Delayed` object should have a (weak?) reference to the key.

The final ingredient is that you need to periodically poll this queue, to see if something expired and has to be evicted. Don't necessarily add a thread to do this, you could just piggyback on whatever thread is accessing the `LoadingCache`. Just before accessing the cache, eg:

```
private void drainCache() {
  MyDelayed expired;
  while ((expired = delayedQueue.poll()) != null) {
    K key = expired.getReference();
    if (key != null) { // this only in case if you hold the key in a weak reference
      loadingCache.invalidate(key);
    }
  }
}

..
V lookup(K key) {
  drainCache();
  return loadingCache.getUnchecked(key);
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, interesting... I will study that a little more. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Mentioned Caffeine library provides this functionality. You just need to provide your own implementation of Expiry. The expiry can depend on key, value or whatever you decide e.g:

```
    .expireAfter(new Expiry<CacheKey, CacheValue>() {
                        @Override
                        public long expireAfterCreate(@NonNull CacheKey key, @NonNull CacheValue value, long currentTime) {
                            return calculateBasedOnKey(key);
                        }
                        @Override
                        public long expireAfterUpdate(@NonNull CacheKey key, @NonNull CacheValue value, long currentTime, @NonNegative long currentDuration) {
                            return calculateBasedOnValue(value);
                        }    
                        @Override
                        public long expireAfterRead(@NonNull CacheKey key, @NonNull Long CacheValue, long currentTime, @NonNegative long currentDuration) {
                            return currentDuration; //not modifying the expiration time
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use the explicit invalidate to defined exactly which entries should be evicted, but that's not probably what you want.

You can give different weights for entries though. It's not perfect, but you can guide the cache to evict entries which are less important. See [Weighter](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html#weigher%28com.google.common.cache.Weigher%29), entries with weight 0 will not be evicted by size-based eviction.

Answer (score 0):

**In case the entries are big and you need to conserve memory**, I don't think there's a nice solution, but these hacks come in mind:

- Use a `PriorityQueue` ordered by the expiration time for manually removing the entries. If you want to be sure that no expired entry gets use, you need to combine this with the solution by hoaz; the queue only prevents the useless entries from occupying memory.
- You wrote "some associated values may expire and others may not", which suggest that the expiration delay is the same for all expiring entries. This would allow using a simpler and faster `Queue` (e.g. `ArrayDeque` instead of the `PriorityQueue`).
- In case the expiration delay is rather large, you could let all entries expire and reinsert those which should live forever in a `RemovalListener`. This can fail in two ways: 1. You may get a miss in the meantime. 2. The removals and re-inserts may cost a lot of CPU time.

Answer (score -1):

you could use caffeine library which is inspired by Guava. 
Here is an example usage from github repo

```
LoadingCache<Key, Graph> graphs = Caffeine.newBuilder()
    .expireAfterAccess(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)

LoadingCache<Key, Graph> graphs = Caffeine.newBuilder()
    .expireAfterCreate(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
```

https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine

Comment: the example you provided does not provide a way to change the expiry at the key level. the example you provided applies the expiry policy to the entire map.

Comment: Note that it is doable with caffeine though, but I don't have an example to provide right now.

Comment: It is doable with the newer Caffeine version, you can customize expiry/eviction per entry
https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Eviction#time-based